# Polymer on-click event inside content wont trigger?

Tags: javascript, polymer, dom-events

I'm very new to Polymer so don't shoot me..

How do I use the `core-icon-button` on-click event to trigger a method that is contained inside of its parent polymer-element aka `my-component`.

Below is an example of what I'm trying to achieve. You can see that there is an element called `my-component` and inside that there is a `core-icon-button` with an `on-click` event.
I want to be able to listen to the event from inside `my-component`.
I don't want to have to place the `core-icon-button` inside `my-component`.

```
<my-component>
    <core-icon-button
        icon="menu"
        on-click="{{theTrigger}}">
    </core-icon-button>
</my-component>


<polymer-element name="my-component">
    <template>
        <div>  
            <content id="content"></content>
        </div>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            theTrigger: function(e){
                console.log('it works');
            }
        });
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found a solution to my problem by adding 'eventDelegates'

```
<my-component>
    <core-icon-button button-one icon="menu"></core-icon-button>
    <core-icon-button button-two icon="favorite"></core-icon-button>
</my-component>


<polymer-element name="my-component">
    <template>
        <div>
            <content></content>
        </div>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            eventDelegates: {
              tap: 'tapHandler'
            },
            tapHandler: function(e) {
                if(e.target.hasAttribute('button-one')){
                    console.log( 'i am button one' );
                }else if(e.target.hasAttribute('button-two')){
                    console.log( 'i am button two' );
                }

            },
        });
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Answer (score 1):

For future visitors, Here is a sample of how to deal with the "on-click" when **not** using `<content></content>` tags, which is slightly different from what @7immy asked & solved. (using the newer Polymer v1.0.0 conventions). *Beginners Note: Don't forget to import paper-material, paper-icon-button, paper-dialog, etc, and instantiate component to fully run this sample.*

Note that we're using polymer's **"on-click"** and not **"onclick"**.

```
<dom-module id="x-sample">
  <template>
    <paper-material elevation="1">
      <div class="horizontal layout">
        <span class="paper-font-body2 flex">Location Information</span>
          <paper-icon-button icon="info" data-dialog="location-info" on-click="openDialog"></paper-icon-button>
      </div>
    </paper-material>

    <paper-dialog id="location-info">
      <div>
        test
      </div>
    </paper-dialog>

  </template>
</dom-module>

<script>
  Polymer({
    is: 'x-sample',
    openDialog: function(e) {
      var button = e.target;
      while (!button.hasAttribute('data-dialog') && button !== document.body) {
        button = button.parentElement;
      }

      if (!button.hasAttribute('data-dialog')) {
        return;
      }
      var id = button.getAttribute('data-dialog');
      var dialog = document.getElementById(id);
      if (dialog) {
        dialog.open();
      }
    }
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

the short answer is "you can't". theTrigger method is in a diff scope then the core-icon-button cause that method it is in the shadowDom of the my-component element.  you can put the button inside the element and it will work. other wise you have to make another method that will target the my-component element and call the method

`document.querySelector('my-component').theTrigger();`